# Keep only the newest data with Spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, databricks

I am streaming data like this: `time`, `id`, `value`
I want to keep only one record for each `id`, with the newest `value`. What is the best way to deal with this problem?
Prefer to use Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import rank, col, monotonically_increasing_id
window = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("time",'tiebreak')
df_s
 .withColumn('tiebreak', monotonically_increasing_id())
 .withColumn('rank', rank().over(window))
 .filter(col('rank') == 1).drop('rank','tiebreak')
 .show()
```

Rank and tiebreaks are added to remove duplicates or ties across and within window partitions.

Comment: will it work with structured streaming?